# Send JSON request body without identifiers SPRING Boot

Tags: java, json, xml, spring-boot, rest

I am consuming a legacy rest service that receives xml text in the body but is sent as json as shown in the following image

[Postman source request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Wbz.png)

I have done the process to transform the previous request to a request that receives a JSON in normal format
[New JSON request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIyLB.png)

And then I transform it into the format that asks me for the source request, my problem is that I do not know how to send my string request because I get the following error when I try to send it
[Request error new http request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDGOV.png)

I get the same error when I sent in my source request in plain text format
[Plain text error legacy http request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuYic.png)

however in code I already transformed this text into JSON format but probably incorrectly,in the following sample code the http entity is the xml string object required by the legacy service

```
@Value("${client.medExpInsuranceQuotation.uri}")
private String clientUri;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("restTemplategetPolicyWs")
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Override
public Object callMedicalExpenseInsuranceQuotation(MedicalExpenseInsuranceQuotationRequestClient requestClient) {
    
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Object json = gson.toJson(requestClient.getXml(), String.class);
    System.out.println("Object: "+json); 
    
    HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(json);
    log.info(requestClient.getXml());
    ResponseEntity<ResponseBean<Object>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(clientUri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseBean<Object>>() {
    });
    
    return responseEntity.getBody().getPayload();
}
```

**Notes:**
The legacy service only receives the body in the format indicated in image 1 (Postman source request)

if I try to send the body in traditional json format with an attribute identifier
[attemp send normal json format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV8UG.png)

I get the following error without information

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred."
}
```

I hope you can help me greetings

Answer (score 0):

That rest service **is** consuming json format. Note the double quotes at the start and the end of the payload - this makes it `json string`. Not `json object`, or `json array`, but `json string`. You need to transform the `xml` payload into json string and send the correct content type header - `application/json`.

**Edit:** To get `json string` first you need the `xml` as a string(it's already a string, i know that sounds strange, but can't explain it better). Then you call `toJson()` on that xml. Something similar to this:

```
String xml = "<xml><tag></tag></xml>";
String jsonString = gson.toJson(xml);
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

Comment: Do you know any way to perform the conversion I have only found for JSON object  not for JSON string? I would appreciate it very much

Comment: @DiegoValenciaMaya Check edit.